# Determining if a node in a tree is full

Tags: java, recursion, tree, nodes

I am trying to determine if all nodes in an m-ary tree are full. I think I have the general idea down, but I'm not sure. Here's what I've done so far.

In my TreeNode class, I have the following method.

```
    public class TreeNode
    {
       private String label;
       private String message;
       private TreeNode[] nodes;
       private int numChildren;
       private TreeNode parent;
       private String prompt;

           ***other methods and constructors***

      public boolean isFull()
    {
      for(int i = 0; i < numChildren; ++i)
      {
        if(nodes[i] == null)
            return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
```

where numChildren is the number of total possible children in the array nodes[] (or just nodes.length) and nodes[] is an array of all the children nodes of the current node. 
Also, it might be helpful to know that my TreeNodes are doubly-linked, so I can retrieve the parent node of the current node if need be.

Then, in my Tree class, I have the following recursive method.

```
    public boolean allNodesFull(TreeNode n)
    {
      boolean allFull = false;
      if(!n.isFull())
      {
        return allFull;
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < n.getNumChildren(); ++i)
      {
        allFull = allNodesFull(n.getChild(i));
      }
      return allFull;
    }
```

Comment: The way it is now `allFull` can never be `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested it, hope you already have a testcase prepared and tell us if it works ;)

```
public boolean allNodesFull(TreeNode n) {
  if(!n.isFull()) {
    return false;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < n.getNumChildren(); ++i) {
    if (!allNodesFull(n.getChild(i))) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```